# Vue dynamically binding to class does not work

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3

I have some code in a Vue component that sort of replicates an Accordion, and I want a drop down arrow to rotate by 90deg when the current Item is active. however no matter what I try nothing works.

```
<template>
  <div
    class="short-term__table"
    v-for="(credit, index) in credits"
    :key="index"
  >
    <div class="row ribbon">
      
      <div class="col" @click="showDetails(index)">
        <i
          class="caret-right fas fa-caret-right"
          :class="credit.active ? 'active' : ''"
        >
        </i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <CreditDetails v-if="credits[index].active" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CreditDetails from "./credit-item-details.component";
export default {
  components: {
    CreditDetails,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      credits: [
        {

          active: false,
        },
        {
          active: false,
        },
        {
          active: true,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showDetails(index) {
      this.credits[index].active = !this.credits[index].active;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

  .active {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }

</style>
```

This works when the component is created, but the class doesent update when the data changes?

so question:
Why does credit.active not update the class binding.

Comment: Probably your problem is in the CSS and not in the Vue. Try to put the ʻactive` class attached to elements for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing array item by its index and this will not work. When you mutate an array item by index Vue can not detect it and the template will not rerender. This is mentioned in [VueJS docs.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays)

You can update array item like this:

```
showDetails(index) {
  this.$set(this.credits, index, {
    ...this.credits[index],
    active: !this.credits[index].active
  })
},
```

Or like this:

```
showDetails(index) {
  this.credits.splice(index, 1, {     
    ...this.credits[index], active: !this.credits[index].active   
  })
}
```

Please read VueJS documentation about reactivity in depth.

Comment: I am using vue 3 and its throwing this.$set is not a function?

Comment: Then you can try this:
`this.credits.splice(index, 1, {
    ...this.credits[index],
    active: !this.credits[index].active
  })`
I have also updated answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is still does not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in the following example:

```js
const {
  createApp,
  computed,
  onMounted,
  watch
} = Vue;



const app = createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      credits: [{
          title: "title 1",
          active: false,
        },
        {
          title: "title 2",
          active: false,
        },
        {
          title: "title 3",
          active: true,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showDetails(index) {
      this.credits[index].active = !this.credits[index].active;
    },
  },
});


app.mount('#app');
```

```css
.active {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="short-term__table" v-for="(credit, index) in credits" :key="index">
    <div class="row ribbon">

      <div class="col" @click="showDetails(index)">
        <h3>{{credit.title}}</h3>
        <i class="caret-right fas fa-caret-right" :class="credit.active ? 'active' : ''">
        >
        </i>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but i suggest to bind the icon name to the active field :

```
<i :class="`caret-${credit.active?'down':'right'} fas fa-caret-${credit.active?'down':'right'}`" >
```

Comment: you're welcome, could you share some running code to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to trigger vue to re-render you will have to use the [this.$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects) method from vuejs.

Change your `methods`-block to the following:

```
methods: {
   showDetails(index) {
     this.$set(this.credits[index], 'active', !this.credits[index].active);
   }
 }
```

Comment: I am using vue 3 and doing this throws this.$set is not a function